# Set Automatic Model Publishing - Data Management API

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360, autodesk-data-management

I can find the [PublishModel](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/PublishModel/) and [PublishModelWithoutLinks](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/PublishWithoutLinks/) features in the Commands Endpoint of the Data Management V2 API, but I was hoping someone would be able to show me where we can setup Scheduled Publishing (Design Collaboration) on an Item.

I was expecting to find an endpoint where I could set a Publishing Schedule on a Folder.

Is this somewhere in another API or does the functionality not exist?

Comment: Unfortunately, APS has not exposed API of Design Collaboration, so the feature Scheduled Publishing is not available. Sorry for the bad news. With the two commands you mentioned, I think you would need to build custom scheduling to call  the commands with your scripts.